# Node.js example not working

Tags: node.js

I followed the two examples on: http://nodejs.org/

The first one worked.  Then I tried the second one, which displayed the below error in terminal and ended the process when I entered in the url (localhost:8000).  It compiled fine.

```
$ node node.js

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:556:19)
```

Some search results said that it may have been that the port is already in use, but I changed the port in the second example, but still no use.

When I visited localhost:8000 (same port in the code), the webpage displays this:

```
Echo server
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.149 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I copied the code from the node.js website exactly, and also tried changing the port numbers.  Not sure what is wrong.

`Edit`: responding to comments

- No firewall.
- OS: Linux Mint 15
- Node v0.10.25

Processes:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
29150 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
29226 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: is there any firewall active?

Comment: Are you sure you terminated the process from the other example, as it might have been using the same port? If you right-click 'run' multiple JS files in IntelliJ for example, it actually doesn't kill the run process from your prior run first, for example.

Comment: The second example is a TCP server, not an HTTP server. It won't work from your browser. You will need to connect to it via telnet, for example issue the following from your Linux terminal "telnet localhost 1337"

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in Hector's comment: the second example is a TCP Server.  It is starting up properly (no port already used issues).  When you make an HTTP request against this the following will happen

- Your browser sends HTTP protocol data to the TCP socket
- node.js writes "Echo Server" back
- node.js writes HTTP protocol chatter it received from the browser back (that's why you're seeing the "funny" stuff on the "webpage")
- Your browser closes the socket (probably it is waiting for a timeout, so this might take quite a while)
- At this point node.js has a pipe open to a writable socket stream and will thus send an error event to the readable socket stream (both of them are `var socket` here)
- This error is not handled, hence you see the exception

To "fix" this, either don't use a browser, i.e., don't close the socket from the client side (for example you can talk to your script with telnet) or add to your program a handling of the error event like this

```
socket.on('error', function() {
    console.log("Error is properly handled");
});
```

(preferably before the call to`socket.write`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I am new to web programming.  Are the HTTP and TCP servers supposed to be used together, or do I choose one over the other?  What's the difference?

Comment: Your and any other browser speaks HTTP, so this is what you should use for any web programming.  TCP is lower-level and on application level you wouldn't use it; it is however used in the internal implementation of the HTTP libraries of node.js or would be used to implement any other protocals based on it such as POP3 or IMAP.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http#Technical_overview